# Create list<string> dynamically

Tags: c#

I want to create a list in a button click event...every time the button is clicked a new list should be created having different name than the previous one...
Can anyone please help me out...I'm stuck on it...

Comment: What do you mean by "a new list should be created having different name"? Perhaps you could post an example of something you've already tried so we can get a better feel for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Lists don't have names... *variables* and *fields* have names. It sounds like you might want a list of lists, or a dictionary of lists.

Comment: public List<string> str = new List<string>();
        public void check()
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < sub.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkbx[i].Checked == true)
                {                  
                    str.Add(checkbx[i].Text);
                }
            }
        }

Here, the checked checkboxes will be different at all time...
So, I want to store the different set of choices each time in different List<string>...
The code given above is in buttonclick2 and I want to create a new list each time in buttonclick3...

Comment: @ shiv09 add the code to the question by clicking edit(below the question). and try to format it

Comment: You can try marking answers for the already asked questions by clicking on the CheckMark to the left of answers.

Answer (score 2):

Better create `List<List<string>>`

```
List<List<string>> lls = new List<List<string>>();

Button_Click()
{
    List<string> str = new List<string>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < sub.Count; i++) 
    { 
        if (checkbx[i].Checked == true) 
        { 
            str.Add(checkbx[i].Text); 
        } 
    }       
    lls.Add(str);
}
```

hence their names would be lls[0], lls[1],... etc

Comment: hey thanks a lot...but li'l bit of confusion...how do I add items to lls[0] on clicking the button once and then to lls[1] on next button click and so on....

Comment: The order it is added to the list lls is automatic. The first button click will add it to lls[0] and the second to lls[1] and so on. In your code i could see str is the list having all the checkedbox texts. Just add it to the collection lls like this: lls.Add(str) after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

List objects doesn't have names, variables have names.

Creating variables dynamically is mostly useless, especially in compiled languages. What you want is a collection where you can store multiple lists, e.g. a list of lists:

```
public List<List<string>> str = new List<List<string>>();

public void check() {
  List<string> subs = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 0; i < sub.Count; i++) {
    if (checkbx[i].Checked) {
      subs.Add(checkbx[i].Text);
    }
  }
  str.Add(subs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary of lists where the key is the list name and the value is the list itself.

```
//Defining Dictionary
Dictionary<string, List<string>> ListDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

//Add lists in Dictionary 
OnClick(string listname)
{
ListDict.Add(listname, new List<string>());
}

//Add values in List  
ListDict[listname].Add("xyz");
```